# Proof verification of part of Urysohn's Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I would like to know if the following proof for Urysohn's Lemma  is correct.

> If $E ⊆ \mathbb R^d $ is nonempty, then $f(x) = \text{dist}(x, E) = \{\inf|x − z| : z ∈ E\}$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R^d$.

**Proof:**

Note, by triangle inequality, for all $z$
\begin{eqnarray*}
|x-z| & \leq  & |x − y|+|y-z|\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Taking infimum on both sides, this yields,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\inf_{z\in E}|x-z| & \leq  & |x − y|+\inf_{z\in E}|y-z|\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Finally,
\begin{eqnarray*}
|f(x)-f(y)| & = & \{ \{\inf|x − z| : z ∈ E\}-\{\inf|x − z| : z ∈ E\}\}\\ 
            & \leq & |x-y|    
\end{eqnarray*}

Which can be used to show that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ where $\delta=\epsilon$. This completes the proof.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: As the title/ tag suggests, I wanted to verify this part of the proof.

Comment: It is almost correct. There is a little imprecision in the last step, it should be $$|f(x)-f(y)|= | \inf ... - \inf ...|$$ and you didn't show that this is less than $|x-y|$ (you showed that $\inf ... - \inf ... \le |x-y|$).

Comment: But I thought I did not need to show that. $ \inf...−\inf...≤|x−y|$ should be enough for my last step, right?

Comment: The question should not be only clear from the tag and the title; instead the body of the post should be self-contained.